# Enlightened Badge awarded after (three!) previously submitted answers were deleted

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, badges

The Enlightened Badge's description states:

> **First to answer** and accepted with score of 10 or more.

I was awarded this just now for answering [Cannot remove commas from input type number value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408182/cannot-remove-commas-from-input-type-number-value), which yesterday prompted three previous incorrect answerers to delete their answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31408321/1317805), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31408307/1317805) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31408280/1317805)).

Whilst it appears I was certainly more *enlightened* than those other users on the matter at hand: should I really have received this, being the fourth person to post an answer?

If this is intentional, are there time restrictions on this? Could a user delete their first answer several months down the line and then see the system award this badge to the latter-posted accepted answer?

Comment: Among other things, this means that spam posts that get deleted for being spam can't block the badge to someone who clearly earned it, by not only answering, being accepted, and having a score of 10 or more, but also not advertising viagra or opportunities to meet hot singles in your area.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional. Last first man standing wins the badge.

Comment: "Last first man standing" is surprisingly comprehensible.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy clarification!

Comment: I'm going to use "last first man standing" a lot more often now. Thanks Martijn!

Comment: How do you determine a poster is a woman, and thus prevent them from getting the badge?

Comment: @Yakk: When (or, more probably, I mean 'if') SO releases its diversity information for its user population, you will find — sadly — that the female section of the world population is depressingly under-represented and the odds of a random user being female are rather small (1 in 6 to 1 in 10 would be my guess, and I wouldn't be dreadfully surprised to find the ratio of females to males is even more skewed than that).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler About [1 in 17](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#profile-gender)

Comment: @Barry: that's even worse than I suspected, by quite a margin...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "Software development has a gender balance problem. Our internal stats suggest the imbalance isn't quite as severe as the survey results would make it seem, but there's no doubt everyone who codes needs to be more proactive welcoming women into the field." Also, a result self-selected 25,744 people out of SO's users is difficult to assess as indicative of much.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Bradbury_(speed_skater)

Comment: And we wonder why there is an imbalance.

Comment: I think as the older developers retire, the balance will shift to something a little better (but still not great.)  I'm aware that when I go to meetings, there are many older and younger men, but while there are younger women, those of us in our 60s are FAR less common than men in that age range.  Which makes me laugh at my own work situation, where 2 or our five developers are women over 60.  Just an odd outlier in the development world.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Proudly trying to even the odds :)